# Function, that returns peak values

Tags: python, iterator

```
def peaks(iterable):
    z = []
    i = iter(iterable)
    v2 = next(i)

    try:
        while True:
            v1, v2 = v2, next(i)
            if v1 > v2:
                z.append(v1)
            elif v1 < v2:
                continue
    except StopIteration:
        pass

    return z
```

This function returns a list of int for those values in the iterable that are bigger than the value preceding and following them: `peaks([0, 1, -1, 3, 8, 4, 3, 5, 4, 3, 8])` returns `[1, 8, 5]`. This result means the values 1, 8, and 5 are strictly bigger than the value preceding and following them.

But when I took `[0, 1, -1, 3, 8, 4, 3, 5, 4, 3, 8]` it returns `[1, 8, 4, 5, 4]` instead of `[1, 8, 5]`.

And when I took `[5, 2, 4, 9, 6, 1, 3, 8, 0, 7]` it returns `[5, 9, 6, 8]` instead of `[9, 8]`.

Can someone tell me how to fix it? Thanks.

Comment: "elif v2 < v2:"? Are you sure?

Comment: ok...  I changed it.  but it still produces the same result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are returning values, which are bigger than the following. You also need to check if they are bigger than previous.

```
def peaks(iterable):
    z = []
    i = iter(iterable)

    try:
        v2 = next(i)
        v3 = next(i)
        while True:
            v1, v2, v3 = v2, v3, next(i)
            if v2 > v1 and v2 > v3:
                z.append(v2)
    except StopIteration:
        pass

    return z

print(peaks([0, 1, -1, 3, 8, 4, 3, 5, 4, 3, 8]))  # [1, 8, 5]
```

Won't find peak in `[0, 1, 1, 0]`. Hopefully, that is what you want.